# how to sort value group by in pandas

Tags: python-3.x

data['state'] consist of states. data['new'] consist of close and open.
I want only open  in new column to group by with state column.

'data.groupby(['State','new']).size().unstack().fillna(0).sort_values('close', ascending=False)'

```
output:
  new              close    open
  State     
Georgia         12.185120   15.473888
Florida         11.775044   7.543520
California      9.314587    11.798839
Illinois        7.908612    5.609284
Pennsylvania    6.444054    3.868472
Tennessee       5.623902    9.090909
Michigan        5.389572    4.448743
Washington      4.393673    4.448743
Maryland        3.690685    2.901354
Colorado        3.397774    4.255319
New Jersey      3.280609    3.675048
Indiana         2.929115    1.740812
Massachusetts   2.929115    2.127660
Texas           2.870533    4.255319
Virginia         2.870533   2.127660
Oregon          2.108963    2.514507
Minnesota       1.698887    0.773694
Mississippi     1.347393    3.094778
Alabama         0.995899    1.740812
Utah            0.937317    1.160542
South Carolina  0.878735    0.580271
Arizona         0.820152    1.160542
District Of 
Columbia        0.820152    0.386847
Louisiana       0.702988    0.193424
New Mexico      0.644405    0.773694
Connecticut     0.527241    0.580271
West Virginia   0.468658    0.580271
New Hampshire   0.468658    0.773694
Delaware        0.468658    0.773694
Arkansas        0.351494    0.000000
New York        0.351494    0.000000
Kentucky        0.234329    0.580271
Maine           0.175747    0.386847
North Carolina  0.175747    0.000000
Missouri        0.175747    0.193424
Ohio            0.175747    0.000000
Vermont         0.117165    0.193424
District of
Columbia        0.058582    0.000000
Rhode Island    0.058582    0.000000
Iowa            0.058582    0.000000
Kansas          0.058582    0.193424
Nevada          0.058582    0.000000
Montana         0.058582    0.000000



I want sort value by open.can anyone help me.
```

Comment: what is open.can in your question?

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question (added), and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). Plus, what is your *question*?

Answer (score 1):

```
is_open = data['new'] == 'open' # Returns dataframe with true/false
open_data = data[is_open] # Shows entry if is_data entry is true
```